# Global Exception Manager in Node

Tags: node.js, exception

I'm using `process.on('uncaughtException')` to catch any exceptions that would unexpectedly come up.  In the function I write the data to a file, send an email, in the future it will likely do more.

Is there a way I can encapsulate the `process.on()` event in a file, then somehow require it in all the files that make up the application so I don't need to add that chunk of code to each file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Node normally runs in a single process, so you only need `process.on('uncaughtException')` in one place.

The exception is if you use the cluster module or otherwise spawn other node processes, in which case you need the `process.on('uncaughtException')` loaded once for each process, but still not once for each file.

(Be careful doing too much in this handler, because by this point the process is considered unstable. I'm also not sure if async work is guaranteed to be run. The [docs](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_warning_using_uncaughtexception_correctly) say that the correct use of 'uncaughtException' is to perform *synchronous* cleanup of allocated resources.)

Comment: I'm using PM2 to kick off~20 different JS files with Node.  They are all part of the greater application but each run as a separate process.  Sounds like I just need to include that chunk of code in each JS file I start with PM2?

Comment: If you're launching different processes, yes, you need to bind the event in each process. You can still put that listener in a single file and require it from one file loaded by every process you're spawning.